# S22 IMAP searching for unseen messages isn't working

Tags: c#, imap

I've encountered a bit of an odd problem with my IMAP parsing code. I'm currently working on a small test solution which would allow me to check the IMAP server every 10 seconds using the S22 library for Unseen messages and display them in a command-line output. However, if I create an ImapClient and the first search for unseen messages returns nothing, at which point I send a new email to the inbox, the Client never manages to find the new email. After closing and running the code again though, it finds the new email without any problems.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'm not sure if not using IMAP IDLE to update is causing any issues here - unfortunately, AOL doesn't support IMAP IDLE.

This is the relevant snippet of code below:

```
using (ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("imap.aol.com", 993, recieve_email_IMAP_test.Credential_AES.DecryptString(g_key, encryptedEmail, g_iv),
                recieve_email_IMAP_test.Credential_AES.DecryptString(g_key, encryptedPass, g_iv), AuthMethod.Login, true))
            {
                IEnumerable<uint> uids = Client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());

                while (uids.Count() == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No new emails. Sleeping for 10 seconds...");
                    uids = Client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());
                    Thread.Sleep(10000); // sleep for 10 seconds and wait before polling again
                }
                recieve_email_IMAP_test.helperFuncs.imapParser(uids, Client); // used for parsing new emails later
                Client.Logout();
            }
```

Comment: When I worked with it before, AOL would not ever update an existing connection with new email, presumably cause they intend a `connect, download, disconnect` model.    What _may_ work is to re-`SELECT` the inbox, which may cause them to rescan, but otherwise you may have to disconnect.  10 seconds is also extremely short, is your timing constraint really that tight?  It may get you banned.

Comment: Thank you for the good response @Max - I will try what you said and see how it goes. In terms of timing constraints, I'm not too sure yet, but the end use-case will involve looking through at the least hundreds of emails daily. I imagine i could probably go with polling every minute or a bit longer in my final product.